# What is the difference between "I ask that you be on time." and "I ask that you are on time."

Tags: word-usage

Does "be on time" focus on the resultant state? My Japanese friend asked me this question today and I really wasn't sure aside from "are" maybe focusing on future tense and "be" focusing on now?

Answer (score 0):

It should be the first one--"be on time." "I ask that..." invokes the subjunctive mood, which is "be," not "are."

Comment: Why should it be in the subjunctive-or-is-it when CGEL state unequivocally that the indicative cannot be said to be an ungrammatical choice here? This has been covered here so many times.